# Update Subversion (to 1.8.9) on Mavericks

Tags: svn, xcode5, osx-mavericks

I try update my Mavericks svn 1.7.10 to 1.8.9 like in [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/681405/how-to-install-svn-1-8-5-with-neon-on-mavericks/758837#758837?newreg=9e084e0d9f7c4e9386a6c2f9e486c8a3):

```
cd ~/Downloads/subversion-1.8.9
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-serf=/usr/local/serf
make
sudo make install
```

but after I type *make* I see

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Does `configure` output any errors?

Comment: this? An appropriate version of serf could not be found, so libsvn_ra_serf
will not be built.  If you want to build libsvn_ra_serf, please
install serf 1.2.1 or newer.

configure: error: Serf was explicitly enabled but an appropriate version was not found.

Comment: Sounds like you need to install serf 1.2.1 or newer first then...?

Comment: Yes, but if I try:
curl -O https://serf.googlecode.com/files/serf-1.2.1.tar.bz2
   tar -xvf serf-1.2.1.tar.bz2
   cd serf-1.2.1
   ./configure --prefix=/home/myUserName/local
   make install - 
I see same output after "make install":
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.

Comment: The error is - checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/Users/********/Downloads/serf-1.2.1':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.

Comment: Try running `xcode-select --install` at a command prompt.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I remind you that can edit questions when you need to provide further info. It's impossible to get code markup right in a single-line comment box with no preview.